# Why does Perl's string multiplication not warn on undef?

Tags: perl, warnings, undef

Under

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $foo = undef;
```

the expressions

```
$foo . ''
```

and

```
"$foo"
```

both produce

```
Use of uninitialized value $foo in ... at ...
```

but the following expression gives the empty string without warning:

```
$foo x 1
```

Anyone knows why? I mean, it's cool to have a nice stringification idiom (`$_ x 1` is quite much shorter than `defined ? "$_" : ''`), but it feels a bit weird.

Comment: I'm sure it wasn't intentional, at least not initially.

Comment: `perldoc perlop` (search for "Multiplicative Operators") doesn't say anything about the behavior of `x` with an `undef` left operand. I agree it's probably unintentional.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I once saw a show with a scene in a law school class. The instructor presented two similar cases to his students and asked why did they result in different rulings. It's because the rulings were made by judges, and judges are people, he eventually explained.

That should warn. The developers that work on Perl are people. Run `perlbug` to send a bug report if you wish.